# How do I count only Russian characters in a bilingual MS Word 2007 document?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I have an MS Word 2007 document in which some paragraphs are written in English and some in Russian. I'm translating the Russian parts into English, and I need to know how many characters there are in Russian, in order to write an invoice.

I tried using the Search function: I used the "language" option and "select all", but it only highlighted all Russian characters in yellow. How do I actually count the Russian characters?

The text is large, the Russian-language paragraphs are found in different parts of it, and it would be painfully slow to select them all by hand.

Comment: After selecting them, copy and paste them into a blank document.

Comment: @Spiff - I chose "Russian language" in the Find dialog, then chose "Select All", but the **Copy** command is not available. And I cannot select them by hand, the document is huge and they are all scattered across different parts of it. So your advice does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading highlight, you can click "find in" - "main document", it'll select all occurrences, so you'll be able to copy it to a new document and count occurrences.
(or alternatively, save your document with a different name, select all English text and delete it)

Above mentioned method works only if you've set language of the document properly.

If no language is set, you can still use wildcard search:

- open find and replace dialog
- check "use wildcards
- for find what enter:
  `[а-яА-Я ,.\?\!]{5,255}`
  (`а` and `А` are cyrillic characters too!)

  - you can include as many punctuation characters and numbers in your expression as you need.

    - some of them, like ? and ! need to be escaped: `\?` `\!`
  - `5` in the expression above is the minimum number of consecutive characters to be considered as a russian text (if set it too small (e.g. 2), then false text e.g. `.` will also be identified as Russian text
  - `255` is the limit in Word, as you select all occurrences anyway, it's not a problem for you
- press "find in" / "main document" to select all occurrences

[image]

Comment: I press "Find In >> Main Document", an error message appears: "The Find field contains the wrong search template"

Comment: have you copied the expression from my answer, or typed it yourself?

Comment: I copied it from your answer. Now I have just typed it myself, and it does not work either.

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to find the good formula, please try to narrow the expression to find out where your word has problem. (e.g. try `[а-я]`, `[а-я]{5,10}`, `[а-яА-Я]{5,10}`, `[а-яА-Я ,.]{5,10}` ...)

Comment: It seems like there should be `;` between the figures in the curly brackets, instead of the comma. Thank you for your answer! +1 now. Sorry for responding late, was busy translating.

Comment: `,` is not a separator in this expression, but a character to match, if you've error using it, then try to escape it (`\,`). Read more on regular expressions in word [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-Word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7)

Comment: Ah, so even in the curly brackets {5,255} the comma is a character for matching.

Comment: No,  there it isn't. You're right. Good spotting!